# Why are some (often long) commands garbled in bash & zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Many times when I enter a long command in bash or zsh (these are the only two shells I am positive I have seen this in) the cursor warps to somewhere in the middle of the string I am entering, can anyone explain why this is, and if something can be done about this?

I have noticed that this often happens when I browse the history of my shell (using arrow keys), when I encounter a long entry, the long, new entry will mix up with the previous entry, rendering the text garbled.

I have an example with short strings, which I just noticed:

History contains:

```
mkdir sune1
mkdir sune2
```

If I navigate to `mkdir sune1`, and then to `mkdir sune2`, I would expect my command line to be `mkdir sune2` (since this is what I have now navigated to) - but instead I get `mkdir1sune2`.

I have noticed this frequently for years, but never let it bother me too much, but I figure it is time for a change! So, any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your prompt string probably has incorrectly escaped nonprinting characters. If you have anything like color changes in your prompt, you need to put `\[` and `\]` around the terminal escape sequences so bash can tell that they don't take up space on screen — otherwise it miscalculates where the actual command is on screen, and updates it in the wrong place. See [this section from TLDP](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/nonprintingchars.html). In zsh, put `%{` and `%}` around escape sequences.

Comment: I do indeed have colors in my prompt, I will try escaping them, or removing them & see if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Consider using zsh's color module. It should avoid the errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159856/how-do-zsh-ansi-colour-codes-work